# Why 你在笑什么？, why not 你笑在什么？

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin

In English, you say

```
What are you laughing at?
I'm laughing at this situation.
```

Here, the preposition "at" refers to "this situation" and "what", respectively. In German it's more clear, since the preposition "über" is always before its target:

```
Über was lachst du?
Ich lache über die Situation.
```

Same in French:

```
De quoi ris-tu?
Je ris de la situation.
```

In Chinese, the same question would be (according to Duolingo and Google Translate):

```
你在笑什么？
```

To me, this sounds like

```
You about laugh what?
Du über lachst was?
Tu de ris quoi?
```

instead of

```
You laugh about what?
Du lachst über was?
Tu ris de quoi?
```

Why is the 在 before the 笑, instead of before the 什么? Is that just "because it is", or am I missing an important point here?

Comment: Because Chinese doesn't need European grammar.

Comment: @神秘德里克 So you're saying that my first suggested answer is correct: "It is so because it is." But as you can see from the accepted answer, it was my misunderstanding of the meaning of 在 that was the problem. Not really a grammar issue.

Comment: 为什么英语里要说What are you laughing at?而不是What you're laughing at?

Comment: "在" is not "at" here. "在" is "ing" here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

「在」in「你在笑什麽」is not equivalent to English *at* in *what are you laughing at?*. To demonstrate by analogy:

- 你在吃什麽 - *what are you eating?*
- 你在做什麽 - *what are you doing?*

「在」is actually equivalent to the suffix *-ing* in *laughing*, *eating*, *doing*. It is English which grammatically requires something as a target for the verb *laughing*; this requirement is redundant in Chinese.

> 你在笑什麽
>
> Literally: You (你) [action in progress / -ing] (在) laugh (笑) what (什麽)?

Perhaps it is easier to see what's being **omitted** in English.

- 你在笑什麽 - *about/at what are you laughing?*
- 你在吃什麽 - *what [food] are you eating?*
- 你在做什麽 - *what [action] are you doing?*

Answer (score 6):

他 **在笑**: He **is laughing**.
他 **在笑** ***你***: He **is laughing** at ***you***.
你 **在笑** ***谁***: You **are laughing** at ***who***? (Who are you laughing at?)
你 **在笑** ***什么***: You **are laughing** at ***what***? (What are you laughing at?)
The word **at** is needed in English but not in Chinese.

Comment: Intuitive explanation _by example_. Focuses on __patterns__ rather than on language theory.